# Image in boxes is not making correct responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put 3 images into 3 boxes.Here I have used bootstrap v3.1.1, here the problem is image is not centering correctly.My medium device output like bellow image

[image]

Here no any problem for medium device but the problem is in small device this is looking like bellow image

[image]

Here image is not cantering. 
I have add bellow html code and a css code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">


<!--------------------------->

    <div class="main-box">
<div class="box" >
    <div class="box1 box sides-hz-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/sss.png" class="img-responsive"></img> </a>
            <div class="list1">
                <li class="header1"><a href="#"><Strong>Select</Strong></a>
                </li>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box1 box sides-hz-2">
        <a href="tce_show_online_users.php"><img src="images/uuu.png" class="img-responsive"></img> </a>
            <div class="list1" style="background:#8C7E63;">
                <li class="header1"><a href="#"><Strong>Online</Strong></a>
                </li>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box1 box sides-hz-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/uuu.png" class="img-responsive"></img> </a>
            <div class="list1">
                <li class="header1"><a href="#"><Strong>Import</Strong></a>
                </li>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>


<!--------------------------->

</div>
</div> <!--end of grid -->
</div> <!----end of row ------->
</div> <!----end of continer ------->
```

Here my own css for image

```
div.box1 img
{
    display:block;
    margin-left:25%;
}
```

May anybody help me for fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You must make the image responsive by adding these properties to img class

```
 .responsive-image{
        height:auto;
        width:100%;
    }
```

Auto height makes sure of resizing image without losing the aspect ratio

If you are using bootstrap, it has class `img-responsive` which will take care of responsiveness of the image.

**Tip :** On resize the image tend to resize and shrink. To make it look nice you can add class `center-block` to keep the image in center of outer div :-)

Comment: I have used boot-strap img-responsive class in here.Is it necessary to make another own responsive class ?

Comment: Nope, if you have used bootstrap then go ahead about img-responsive. That's the way to go :-)